# how to make .app file for OS X using taco CLI of Cordova project

Tags: macos, cordova, taco

I need the .APP file or build Cordova project using Taco CLI Command for OS-X not for IOS. I know how to build cordova project for IOS. I need the command for OS-x. Or other way Please let me know the solutions
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the OSX platform (which requires Cordova 5.3.1+). [Cordova OS X Platform Documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/osx/index.html)

- `taco platform add osx`
- `taco run osx`